# How to set position of UWP application same as people app in windows 10?

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am working on xamarin.uwp application and I want to set runtime position of my app same as [people app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYpVt.png) in windows 10. Where do I need to set position?

Answer (score 0):

> How to set position of UWP application same as people app in windows 10?

`People` icon where in the taskbar is part of taskbar, it is not independent app. And you could use `ContactPanel` to pin a contact on the taskbar base on contact api. For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/my-people-support), and this is code [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ContactPanel). Currently uwp does not provide set app's position manually. If your do want this feature please feel free to post on the [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).